# saving multiple checkboxes values and save to the database using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Hi i have this select checkbox which is the time when i check all the value does pass through it! Now my problem is when i saved into the database it is only one value saved. this is my HTML

```
<p>Sunday</p>
                <input type="checkbox" name="select-all-sunday" id="select-all-sunday" onclick="toggle(this);"> Check All
                <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-sunday[]" id="checkbox-1" value="00:00"> 00:00 <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-sunday[]" id="checkbox-2" value="1:00"> 1:00 <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-sunday[]" id="checkbox-3" value="2:00"> 2:00 <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-sunday[]" id="checkbox-4" value="3:00"> 3:00 <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-sunday[]" id="checkbox-5" value="4:00"> 4:00 <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-sunday[]" id="checkbox-6" value="5:00"> 5:00 <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-sunday[]" id="checkbox-7" value="6:00"> 6:00 <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-sunday[]" id="checkbox-8" value="7:00"> 7:00 <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-sunday[]" id="checkbox-9" value="8:00"> 8:00 <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-sunday[]" id="checkbox-10" value="9:00"> 9:00 <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-sunday[]" id="checkbox-11" value="10:00"> 10:00 <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-sunday[]" id="checkbox-12" value="11:00"> 11:00 <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-sunday[]" id="checkbox-13" value="12:00"> 12:00 <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-sunday[]" id="checkbox-14" value="13:00"> 13:00 <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-sunday[]" id="checkbox-15" value="14:00"> 14:00 <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-sunday[]" id="checkbox-16" value="15:00"> 15:00 <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-sunday[]" id="checkbox-17" value="16:00"> 16:00 <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-sunday[]" id="checkbox-18" value="17:00"> 17:00 <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-sunday[]" id="checkbox-19" value="18:00"> 18:00 <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-sunday[]" id="checkbox-20" value="19:00"> 19:00 <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-sunday[]" id="checkbox-21" value="20:00"> 20:00 <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-sunday[]" id="checkbox-22" value="21:00"> 21:00 <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-sunday[]" id="checkbox-23" value="22:00"> 22:00 <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-sunday[]" id="checkbox-24" value="23:00"> 23:00 <br>
```

this is now my controller

```
$sundays = $request->input('checkbox-sunday');

        foreach($sundays as $sunday){
            echo  $sunday.",";



        }
```

Now the echo $sunday seems the value being passed from the form display correctly. Now upon saving into the database only one value is being saved.

Below is my code upon saving to the database

```
$sundays = $request->input('checkbox-sunday');

        foreach($sundays as $sunday){
            echo  $sunday.",";

            $postRoom = PostRoom::find($id);

            $postRoom->description = $request->get('description');
            $postRoom->checkin_date = $request->get('bookingDate');
            $postRoom->checkin_time = $request->get('checkinTime');
            $postRoom->room_price = $request->get('roomPrice');
            $postRoom->day_sunday = $sunday;
            $postRoom->your_neighbourhood = $request->get('yourNeighbourhood');

            $postRoom->save();

            return redirect('add-your-listing/next-step-3/'.$postRoom->id);



        }
```

what is the best way to saved this one?. Can someone help me? TIA.

Comment: where do you get `$id` from?

Comment: sorry i just added that. i will have to remove that

Comment: don't remove it, it's the most important part, show us where you get the ID from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

normal you spend in your loop and you look for each time the id and save the current give loop so you crush it, the best thing would be to make a table and send this table in this field (sorry for my english)

me i try this.

```
    $sundays = $request->input('checkbox-sunday');

    $sundaysArray = array();

    foreach($sundays as $sunday){
       $sundaysArray[] = $sunday;
    }


    $postRoom = PostRoom::find($id);

    $postRoom->description = $request->get('description');
    $postRoom->checkin_date = $request->get('bookingDate');
    $postRoom->checkin_time = $request->get('checkinTime');
    $postRoom->room_price = $request->get('roomPrice');
    $postRoom->day_sunday = json_encode($sundaysArray);
    $postRoom->your_neighbourhood = $request->get('yourNeighbourhood');

    $postRoom->save();

    return redirect('add-your-listing/next-step-3/'.$postRoom->id);
```

Comment: it says  (2/2) QueryException

Array to string conversion

Comment: it work now! the data being saved is this one 

["8:00","9:00","10:00","11:00","12:00","13:00","14:00","15:00","16:00","17:00","18:00","19:00","20:00","21:00","22:00","23:00"]

Comment: its in json . but i want that it is not something like that. something like this one
8:00, 9:00, 10:00, 11:00 and so on....

Comment: Nickel :) I hope you understood your mistake with my message :)

Comment: but i want upon saving not in json encode something like this 8:00, 9:00, 10:00, and so on.. hmmm

Comment: not at all you go every time in your id and thus overwrite your last string save

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is based on Array to String Conversion, 
you can either use `json_encode()` or `json_decode()` to transform your array when saving and retrieve while reading, or for me, i use `serialize()` and `unserialize()` to store and retrive array sets from a database as string datatype.

```
//read the checkbox input from the form.
$sundaysArray = $request->input('checkbox-sunday');

//while saving 
$postRoom->day_sunday = json_encode($sundaysArray)  //or 
$postRoom->day_sunday = serialize($sundaysArray);

//while reading from database
$sundaysArray = json_decode($postRoom->day_sunday)  //or
$sundaysArray = unserialize($postRoom->day_sunday);
```

either way this works.

Answer (score 0):

Model PostRoom

```
protected $fillable = [
        'bookingDate', 'description', 'checkinTime', 'roomPrice', 'day_sunday', 'your_neighbourhood'];
```

Code

```
     $sundays = $request->input('checkbox-sunday');
     $data = [];
     $hours = []
     foreach($sundays as $sunday){
           $hours[] = $sunday;
     }
     $room = PostRoom::find($id);
     $data['description'] = $request->get('description');
     $data['bookingDate'] = $request->get('bookingDate');
     $data['checkinTime'] = $request->get('checkinTime');
     $data['roomPrice'] = $request->get('roomPrice');
     $data['day_sunday'] = implode(', ' $hours);
     $data['your_neighbourhood'] = $request->get('yourNeighbourhood');
     $room->update($data);

     return redirect('add-your-listing/next-step-3/'.$room->id);
```

Comment: add fillable to PostRoom

Comment: you don't need fillable properties because OP is not doing mass assignment

Comment: did as you like

Answer (score 0):

On your PostRoom model add a protected $casts variable with the following

```php
protected $casts = [
    'day_sunday' => 'array',
];
```

Then update your save method as follows

```php
$postRoom = PostRoom::find($id);

$postRoom->description = $request->get('description');
$postRoom->checkin_date = $request->get('bookingDate');
$postRoom->checkin_time = $request->get('checkinTime');
$postRoom->room_price = $request->get('roomPrice');
$postRoom->day_sunday = $request->get('sundays');
$postRoom->your_neighbourhood = $request->get('yourNeighbourhood');

$postRoom->save();
```

This will store the data in your database as a json_encoded object, but as far as your laravel app is concerned it's an array. When you read the $postRoom->day_sunday property it will return an array matching the one returned from the controller.